# Changing name attribute of input field when using multiple datasets with typeahead.js

Tags: jquery, html, forms, typeahead.js

I am using typeahead.js with multiple datasets as explained [here](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#multiple-datasets). I am not using Bloodhound, so my code looks a little bit different, as seen below

```
$('#search .typeahead').typeahead({
  hint: true,
  highlight: true,
  minLength: 1
},
{
  name: 'football_team',
  source: substringMatcher(football_teams),
  templates: {
    header: '<h3>Football teams</h3>'
  }
},
,{
  name: 'basketball_team',
  source: substringMatcher(basketball_teams),
  templates: {
    header: '<h3>Basketball teams</h3>'
  }
});
```

Since it is using the datasets `football_teams` and `basketball_teams` I want to send a different GET request depending on which dataset was used. For example, if I search for "Arsenal", select it and click enter it should send the folllowing request `?football_team=Arsenal`.

How can I set the `name` attribute of the input field depending on which dataset was used?

I think it should be really easy to implement, but after Googling for a while I couldn't find anything...

Comment: did you try using [Bloodhound-prefetch-example](https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#prefetch)? 
using with respective `prefetch` url for different datasets, seems to be better option;
`source` seems to accept either result **array** or **Bloodhound** object

Answer (score 0):

using [cdn-ref](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typeahead.js/0.11.1/typeahead.bundle.min.js) try with `custom-event` handler for [typeahead:select](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#custom-events) for processing the selected option

usage ref: [sample-code(internal proj)](https://gitlab.com/rran/climate-portal/blob/master/templates/index.html#L951)